# counter variable inside function

Tags: jquery

I have a basic HTML grid like this one:

```
<table>
  <tr id="player1_race">
    <td class="active"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I need the class active to go to the next td element on click and removed from the current element. 
I have something like this:

```
var counter = 1;

$("#player1_race").click(function() {
   var counter = counter + 1
    $("#player1_race > td:nth-child('counter')").addClass('active');
    $('#player1_race > td.active').removeClass('active');
})
```

The counter variable cant be accessed for some reason.

Comment: When you put "var" in front of the "counter" in the function in the click callback, you are redeclaring  "counter" so that it will not be defined, so the statement var counter = counter + 1 will be interpreted as var counter = undefined + 1. Just remove the var to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues. Firstly the use of `var` within the click handler is changing the scope of the variable, so you need to remove it. Secondly, you're not concatenating the variable to the string selector correctly. It would be better in this instance to use `eq()` anyway. Finally, the index of elements starts at `0`, so `counter` should start with that value. Try this:

```
var counter = 0;

$("#player1_race").click(function() {
    counter++;
    $("#player1_race > td").removeClass('active').eq(counter).addClass('active')
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbojqpy9/)

Answer (score 1):

counter variable is unnecessary declared two times in your code.

First remove class active and add the class for the current

```
var counter = 0;

$("#player1_race").click(function() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    $('#player1_race  td.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find("td").eq(counter).addClass('active');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nq42L67v/)